# PHP FTPS fails after host switched FTP domain 'Encountered end of file' error

Tags: php, curl, ftps

I've been connecting to a particular FTP that uses FTPS for years. We were recently informed that they switched to a new domain and we should update our code. The below code always worked with the old domain but fails on the new:

```
        $ftp_server = 'ftps://newdomain.com/file.csv'; 
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ftp_server);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,'user'.':'.'pass');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
        $file = fopen('data.csv', "w+");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        fputs($file, $data);
        curl_close($ch);
        //some code to read file
```

Now, the connection seems to work fine, but it can't retrieve the file. Verbose shows:

```
< 230 Logged on
> PBSZ 0
< 200 PBSZ=0
> PROT P
< 200 Protection level set to P
> PWD
< 257 "/" is current directory.
* Entry path is '/'
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||35009|)
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xxx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xxx (xx.xx.xx.xxx) port 35009
* Connected to ftp.newdomain.com (xx.xx.xx.xxx) port 990 (#0)
> TYPE I
< 200 Type set to I
> SIZE file.csv
< 213 5728398
> RETR file.csv
< 150 Opening data channel for file download from server of "/file.csv"
* Maxdownload = -1
* Getting file with size: 5728398
* Doing the SSL/TLS handshake on the data stream
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* NSS error -5938 (PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR)
* Encountered end of file
```

I've changed nothing except the server name. Any ideas what this error means? I ran this on 2 separate local server to eliminate the chance that it's my local server.

I tried fiddling with the different SSL settings in the code but it always fails.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line solved it. I don't know why

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_CONTROL);
```

Comment: I have looked everywhere, I don't know why that made a difference either, but it did and you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the PASV mode?  This is usually one of the first things to try.

Comment: I tried `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPSV, FALSE);` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPSV, TRUE);` No difference